# Why is std::min_element and company not specialized for std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, boolean, specialization

I have a `std::vector<bool>` instance (`foo`, say), and I need to write a function that returns `true` if all the elements are `true`.

I use

```
return *std::min_element(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

to achieve that, but this has got me thinking: you know the minimum element is `false`, if the container contains at least one `false` value. In other words, you don't need to traverse the whole container to `end()`, which means that a specialisation of `std::min_element` is appropriate, just like a specialisation of `std::vector<bool>` has been deemed appropriate.

Am I missing anything? Or would this be viewed as a premature optimization? Perhaps a good compiler would sort it out anyway.

Comment: That seems better suited for [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) instead.

Comment: Why not use a bitset?

Comment: Why not use `std::any_of` which has that short circuit built into it?

Comment: There's no way I can change the container type. Too much refactoring of production code would be required. PS I adore this site. I've only just started using it, and it's been extremely helpful.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it. (Especially if you write out the example).

Comment: @NathanOliver If the OP wants to know if *all* elements are `true` then `any_of` doesn't seem right. `all_of` also have short -circuitry where it stops if the predicate return `false`.

Comment: `std::any_of` with the predicate set to `false` is presumably what I need to do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But if `any_of` them are false then you know they are not all true.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true (pun not intended). All three of that family, `all_of`, `any_of` and `none_of` could be used, with different predicates depending on what's wanted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude After looking at the code for `any_of` you have to negate its return to get the correct value.  Looks like `all_of` would make more sense here since it returns to the correct value.

Comment: @NathanOliver: My boss is a thoroughbred Englishman, directly decended from the Plantagenets. He will not approve of your changing the spelling of "specialised". I'm American so I'm with you on this.

Comment: @PaulLogue If you want to change it back go ahead.  I was part of an auto edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to specialize `std::min_element` for `std::vector<bool>`.  To get the functionality that you want you can just use `std::any_of` which will stop at the first occurrence.

```
return !std::any_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](auto e){ return e == false; });
```

If we change this to `std::all_of` as [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) suggests then you do not need to negate the return value, which gives you

```
return std::all_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](auto e){ return e; });
```

Which is a little cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: I think I need return `!std::any_of...`

Comment: @PaulLogue Correct.  You want to return `false` if it finds `false`.

Comment: Thank you. I went for `std::all_of` in the end, with `[](auto i){return i;}` as the lambda. Last time I wrote something like `i == true` my boss nearly chopped my head off for being tautologous.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Keeping the parameter as auto as I believe it makes the code more maintainable.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's disputable area, I suppose. If it would be more generic function I would agree with you. However here we know it's bool specialization. So, why not to state that clearly?

Comment: Well, while it is true that `all_of` is more appropriate in specifically boolean context, it sort of misses the more general point of the question. I might still want to use `min_element` in a more generic context, where the element type is not known in advance to be `bool`. In such situation `all_of` is not immediately applicable, while specialized `min_element` would make perfect sense. But it looks like in this case it is responsibility of the user to specialize/branch their code if they want to optimize it in that way. (The same reasoning also applies to elements  of unsigned types.)

Comment: @PaulLogue If I were the boss, I would threaten to chop heads for giving a `bool` the name `i` so typically associated with an index/integer. :P I use `b` in cases where brevity seems to be the overriding factor.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: use [`std::any_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/), which:

> Returns true if pred returns true for any of the elements in the range [first,last), and false otherwise.

meaning that it will return as soon as it finds `false`.

Example:

```
// any_of example
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // std::any_of
#include <vector> 

int main () {
  std::vector<bool> foo = {true, true, true};

  if ( !std::any_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](bool i){return i == false;}) )
      std::cout << "All elements are true\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
All elements are true.
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://ideone.com/lPi3IK)</kbd>

---

Since you don't have a designated [data-structure](/questions/tagged/data-structure) in place, then [`std::min_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) should iterate through the whole vector, since it's a general method.

A specialization could do what you say, where you could take advantage of the `compare` functionality it provides.

Comment: use `auto` and keep everyone happy